# Why is it significant that Arius taught two Wisdoms? Was this a deviation of some kind?

Tags: trinity, church-fathers, arianism, logos, arius

Both Athanasius noted that Arius taught two Wisdoms. Athanasius wrote that in Arius’ theology,

> “There are … two Wisdoms, one God's own who has existed eternally with
> God, the other the Son who was brought into existence. … There is
> another Word in God besides the Son” (RH, 13).

Alexander similarly wrote that Arius stated,

> “Nor is he the Father's true Logos nor the Logos by nature, nor his
> true Wisdom” (RH, 16).
>
> “He came into existence himself through the proper Logos of God and
> the Wisdom which was in God, in which God also made everything and him
> (the Son) with it” (RH, 16).

In Lorentz's summary of Arius’ theology, he said:

> “There are two Logoi and two Wisdoms (Sophiae), and several powers of
> God. … Arius distinguished between an original Reason (Logos) or
> Wisdom immanent from eternity in the Godhead and the Son who was not
> immanent in the Godhead but created, and who could only be given these
> titles loosely or inexactly.” (20)

Why is it significant that Arius taught “two Logoi and two Wisdoms”? Was this a deviation of some kind?

(All references are to RPC Hanson's book, The Search for the Christian Doctrine of God - The Arian Controversy 318-381

Comment: I think some definition is necessary.  One might say that Arius taught such because he had not properly read the Greek scriptures. This is massively apparent from your second quotation. Can you give some guidance as to what you mean by 'Why' ? Is this a philosophical why ? A medical enquiry ? A practical examination ? If Arius did not fully explain himself (and he wrote precious little that remains to us) it is going to be difficult (without opinionated supposition) to arrive at an academic conclusion.

Comment: @NigelJ I changed the question at the top to be the same as the question in the body. Both Alexander and Athanasius mentioned this. It must, therefore, have been significant. But why is it significant? Who on earth would teach one Word or Wisdom? In other words, that God and His Son only has one Word and Wisdom between them.

Comment: Since one Divine nature is shared, in union, in Spirit, I see it as wholly reasonable to perceive that there is one divine wisdom and one divine word. Nothing the Father knows or is aware of is contradictory to anything that the Son knows or is aware of. And the same is true of communicated word.

Comment: @NigelJ Sounds like modalism. Why is that view not modalism?

Comment: No it is not. Father and Son are distinct individuals, yet one in nature. (And therefore of one mind and one wisdom and one word.) I think you need to refer to the documents of the Council of Nicaea.

Comment: @NigelJ Sounds like you say it is not modalism because you say it is not. Nicaea says nothing of one nature, one mind, one wisdom, or one word.

Comment: Well it is said 'we have the mind of Christ'. So if Christ and 'we' have one mind, I cannot see why the Father and the Son do not have one mind. And Christ is called, 'the wisdom of God'. So one wisdom shared by Christ and God. In one Holy Spirit there is unity. And such a unity it is ! (That is, if one be full of that Holy Spirit.)

Comment: @NigelJ To say that the Son is the Father's Wisdom is different from saying that the Father, Son, and Spirit share one 'Wisdom'. As you would be aware, when the Arian Controversy began, Logos-theology was still the standard way of explaining the Son or Logos. It was based on Greek philosophy and said that the Logos always existed as part of God but became a separate hypostasis (reality) when He was "begotten." There was no place for the Spirit as a separate hypostasis in Logos-theology. It seems as if Alexander and Athanasius noted that Arius deviated from this 'tradition.'

Comment: @NigelJ I find your comments a bit confusing. You say Father and Son are "of one mind." We use that expression usually when two people agree on something. You also refer to the verse that says, "We have the mind of Christ." Again, by implication, this refers to different minds that agree. But, in the traditional trinity doctrine, God has one single being and nature and mind and will. Please clarify your view.

Comment: I have been perfectly clear. And I have nothing to add. No further comment.